# C#.NET Bound TexField Will not update value in datarow

Tags: c#, data-binding, datarow

I have somewhat of a strange issue that I need help with.  Given the following code snippet:

```
public partial class CliUpdate : Form
{       

    static DataRow cliRecord;
    static DataView cliView;

    public CliUpdate(DataRow dr)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cliRecord = dr;
        cliView = cliRecord.Table.DefaultView;          
        SetFieldValues();                       
    }               

    void SetFieldValues(){                  
        string recordid = cliRecord["recordid"].ToString();
        cliView.RowFilter = "recordid='" + recordid + "'";          
        tb_ClientName.DataBindings.Add("Text",cliView,"clientname");
        tb_basefolder.DataBindings.Add("Text",cliView,"basefolder");
        cb_CollectionOutput.DataBindings.Add("Text",cliView,"outputtype");
        nud_SmallBalance.DataBindings.Add("Value",cliView,"smallbalance");
```

On the form I have a textbox named tb_basefolder.  If I actually type something in the textbox, the datarow field gets properly updated BUT if I give the textbox a value by setting the .Text property, the value does not get updated on the datarow (ie tb_basefolder.Text = @"c:\test";)  Can someone shed some light?  Have I provided enough information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this work?

```
   tb_basefolder.DataBindings.Add("Text",cliView,"basefolder",  false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

why do you use static members for dataview and datarow?

Comment: Typically I wouldn't but was tinkering with the datarow and datview to see if it made a difference.  I posted the code with the "tinkering" left in accidentally.  Thanks a bunch for your help.